# Bluez 5 Set L2CAP Extended Features Mask

Tags: testing, bluetooth, bluez, l2cap, unicast

I am trying to set my L2CAP extended features mask to enable Unicast Connectionless Data in order to complete Bluetooth Sig certification. I cannot seem to find anywhere to do this. The particular Bluetooth PTS test I am trying to pass is as follows:

> TC_CLS_UCD_BV_01_C: Verify that the IUT has the UCD bit set in the
>   L2CAP Extended Features Mask to indicate support for reception of
>   Unicast Connectionless Data...

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone in the future.

Apparently the L2CAP code is mostly in the kernel subsystems, and not the user space Bluez. Our kernel is fairly old, and thus did not have UCD support built in. We used the kernel backports project to update the bluetooth subsytem portion of the kernel. Now the test runs fine.